# React : How to change route on onChange event of input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, react-hooks

I want to change the Route whenever I input text in input field and pass the input value to `<Search />` component route. this is my input field.

```
<input type="search" value={searchInput} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Search..." />
```

this is the route that I created.

```
<Route path="/search/:searchInput">
   <Search />
</Route>
```

I have handled the input value but can't seem figure how to change the component whenever I enter into input box. can you please help me. I also want to pass the input value to the route.

```
const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("")

const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSearchInput(e.target.value)
}
```

this is my navigation component :

```
const Navigation = () => {
  let history = createHashHistory();
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("")

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSearchInput(e.target.value)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    if (searchInput) {
      params.append("query", searchInput);
    } else {
      params.delete("query");
    }
    history.push({ search: params.toString() });
  }, [searchInput, history]);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className='navigation'>
        <div className="right-content">
          <div className="search">
            <img style={{ padding: "2px" }} src={search} alt="search" />
            <input type="search" value={searchInput} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Search..." />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/search" component={Search}>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default Navigation
```

and this is my Search Component :

```
const Search = () => {

    const value = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("query");

    console.log(value)

}
```

I imported the search component in navigation. I want to go the Search component when I input.

Comment: where does your input field reside ?

Comment: @Shyam it's in my navigation Component. which is in Router. I want to pass the input value field from Navigation component to Search component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the query params.

When you are changing the input , you need to append the input value as a query string to the url . we can do this as below.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    if (searchInput) {
      params.append("query", searchInput);
    } else {
      params.delete("query");
    }
    history.push({ search: params.toString() });
  }, [searchInput, history]);
```

Once the query params are set we can read it from the select component as below.

```
 const value = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("query");
```

**Working Example** - [Search Params Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-sea-6b7ex?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I have the query string. but can't pass it to the another component I mean search. in your example it's working but I can't use the value. it's returning null.

Comment: change your path in the Route from `path="/search/:searchInput"` to `path="/search"`

Comment: Add your code for <Search /> component . And also post how you are reading the search params .

Comment: I have. but it's not even going to the search component.

Comment: in my search component i'm reading the value like `const value = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("query");`

Comment: show all your Routes .  Its difficult with partial code .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233241/discussion-between-amisha-mundra-and-shyam).

Answer (score 1):

```
 import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";    
 constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                redirect: null,   
            }
      }  
      handleChange=(){
          this.setState({
           redirect: "/search/22"
          }); 
      }
      render() {
            if (this.state.redirect) {
                return <Redirect to={this.state.redirect} />
            }
            return (
                <div>
                 <input type="search" value={searchInput} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Search..." />
                </div>
            );
      }
```